# Font weight in table header not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Safari and Firefox the font is bold, but it's not in Chrome. What is going on here? Tried emptying cache.

Safari and Firefox
[image: Safari and Firefox]

Chrome
[image: Chrome]

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <th>Project</th><th>Needed</th><th>Created</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test project 4</td><td>2020-04-15</td><td>2020-02-21 17:22:13</td>
        <td>Test project 3</td><td>2020-03-19</td><td>2020-02-21 17:20:12</td>
        <td>Test project</td><td>2020-02-26</td><td>2020-02-21 14:51:26</td>
        <td>Test project 2</td><td>2020-02-29</td><td>2020-02-21 14:51:26</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

CSS

```
table, td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-weight: light;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working. Add `!important` to the style.

See on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/yLNgpyZ

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Needed</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test project 1</td>
            <td>2020-02-29</td>
            <td>2020-02-21 14:51:26</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Test project 2</td>
            <td>2020-02-29</td>
            <td>2020-02-21 14:51:26</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Test project 3</td>
            <td>2020-03-19</td>
            <td>2020-02-21 17:20:12</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Test project 4</td>
            <td>2020-04-15</td>
            <td>2020-02-21 17:22:13</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table,
td {
     border: 2px solid black;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     text-align: center;
}

th {
     font-weight: 100 !important;
     color: rgb(236, 28, 28);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with the IBM Plex Mono font, since other fonts I can get to work bold in Chrome, but not this one.

Comment: Maybe the font does not have and `font-weight`, Try using `Montserrat font` it has a lot of versions too.

Answer (score 3):

!important is not best practice here because this has the highest level of priority. Use a more defining selector to target the `<th>`, for example

```
table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

or

```
table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```